# Compiler warning for Google Calendar Event Start / End Properties

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar v3 API and I have a Visual Basic application.

It has worked for years and still does but I noticed a warning during compilation concerning:

`Googles.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event`

I init the variable:

```
Dim oEvent As New Data.Event With {
    .Summary = sEvent.strTitle,
    .Description = sEvent.strEventDetails,
    .Location = sEvent.strLocation
}
```

But one bit in particular:

```
Dim eventStartDT As New Data.EventDateTime() With {
        .DateTime = dtDateTimeStart
}

Dim eventEndDT As New Data.EventDateTime() With {
    .DateTime = dtDateTimeFinish
}

oEvent.Start = eventStartDT
oEvent.End = eventEndDT
```

I have looked at the docs:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events

They imply my code it OK. It states:

> ```
>   "start": {
>     "date": date,
>     "dateTime": datetime,
>     "timeZone": string
>   },
>   "end": {
>     "date": date,
>     "dateTime": datetime,
>     "timeZone": string
>   },
> ```

Yet, during compile:

> ... Program.vb(955,26): warning BC40000: 'Public Overridable Overloads Property `DateTime As Date?`' is obsolete: 'This property is obsolete and may behave unexpectedly; please use `DateTimeDateTimeOffset` instead.'.

I am not sure what to do.

[image]

I confirm that the new property is listed:

[image]

Comment: take the advice

Comment: @nbk Sure, I was trying to find a worked example using the new methodology.

Comment: Is that really the precise wording of the warning? I'm guessing not. I think you may have mucked it up when trying to format it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, it is. I copy / pasted it.

Comment: Is there actually a property named `DateTimeDateTimeOffset` available? If so, what type is it? If not, is there maybe a property named `DateTimeOffset` with a type of `DateTimeOffset`? My guess would be that, instead of setting `DateTime` and possibly not `TimeZone`, you're supposed to just set some property that is type `DateTimeOffset`, which inherently includes both the date/time info and the time zone info.

Comment: @jmcilhinney See updated question,

Comment: OK, so there is a property with name. Weird, but there we go. It is indeed type DateTimeOffset, so you just need to set that instead. A DateTimeOffset is like a DateTime but it includes information about the offset from UTC. Just read the documentation for that type, create an appropriate value and assign it to that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this section:

```vb
Dim eventStartDT As New Data.EventDateTime() With {
        .DateTime = dtDateTimeStart
}

Dim eventEndDT As New Data.EventDateTime() With {
    .DateTime = dtDateTimeFinish
}

oEvent.Start = eventStartDT
oEvent.End = eventEndDT
```

should be this:

```vb
Dim eventStartDT As New Data.EventDateTime() With {
        .DateTimeDateTimeOffset = New DateTimeOffset(dtDateTimeStart)
}

Dim eventEndDT As New Data.EventDateTime() With {
    .DateTimeDateTimeOffset = New DateTimeOffset(dtDateTimeFinish)
}

oEvent.Start = eventStartDT
oEvent.End = eventEndDT
```

There is also a constructor that allows you to set the offset from UTC. See the relevant documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset).